# how to kill a zombie process?

Tags: linux, process, kill

I got a two processes during the network drive failure.

```
1 D     0  1199     1  0  80   0 - 19101 wait_o pts/21   00:00:01 rsync
1 Z     0  1226  1199  0  80   0 -     0 exit   pts/21   00:00:00 rsync <defunct>
```

How to kill them?

thanks Arman

Comment: Duplicate : http://serverfault.com/questions/250294/best-way-to-kill-zombie-and-d-state-processes-in-linux

Comment: Yes but it does not help to solve my problem...

Comment: Rebooting doesn't get rid of the zombie process? Or you mean how you're running/killing the process in the first place is the problem?

Comment: @Arman: the post says the only way is rebooting, and so it is. Like @Bart says, it's hard to imagine that rebooting might not fix your problem, unless your problem is that this is a recurrent issue maybe?

Comment: Thanks,Yes, you are right, I dont want to reboot the server, but if it is a only way to do, then I can try to reboot over the WE.

Comment: Actually the second answer to that question is equally correct, and often more practical: If you kill the zombie's original parent the zombie will often go away.  Failing that you're back at rebooting the system.

Comment: no it does not go away, his parent is in the  wait_o mode.

Comment: `kill -s SIGCHLD <PPID>'. Using your example ps output, that would be `kill -s SIGCHLD 1199'

Comment: zombie is dead -- you can't kill something dead. The parent should collect it. If it don't, kill the parent.

Comment: I was not able to reboot the system...brutforce button press solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Send a SIGCHILD signal to the parent process and if that doesn't work kill the parent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process